# Add HashMap to another HashMap

Tags: java, android, android-intent, hashmap

When i try to add hashMap to another HashMap i lose old varaible. How can i fix this problem? My code is something like that.

```
HashMap<String, String> tmp = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

tmp = ((HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("map"));
map.putAll(tmp);
```

when i use this code map elements always equals tmp elements. It is not stored old elements.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please show a concrete example.

Comment: Can you give examples of what was in `map` before `putAll` (I suppose something happens between `new` and `putAll`), what there is in `tmp` and what is in `map` after the `putAll`?

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();` creates a new, empty, HashMap instance. Therefore after a call to `map.putAll(tmp)`, your map would only contain the entries of `tmp`.

If `map` has previous entries, you shouldn't assign a new instance to this variable.

That said, even if `map` had previous entries, putting the entries of `tmp` in it would overwrite the values of all the keys that exist in both `map` and `tmp`.

Comment: i can show tmp's entries but when i add to something else to map i lose old variable and it is show only new elements.

Comment: Then how can solve this overwrite issue. I want to add new elements instead of overwrite

Comment: @duygumersin A Map can only hold  single value for each key. If you want it to hold multiple values for the same key, you can change the value to be a collection. For example, `HashMap<String, List<String>>`. Of course, you wouldn't be able to use putAll in this case. You'll have to iterate over the entries of the source map and add the relevant Strings to the target map

Answer (score 0):

Once you have updated map to not be re-initialized every time, you can avoid overwriting any existing key-value pairs in map by looping as follows:

```
for (String key : tmp.keySet()) {
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, tmp.get(key);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure from your question if this is exactly what you are asking, but it may be useful. Eran's suggestion (using `HashMap<String, List<String>>`) is also a good one if you want to store multiple Strings per key.